# Query inside a query with if statement depending the result

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sccm

so I have a peculiar question about an SSRS report i am created.

```sql
SELECT        rs.Name0, rs.User_Name0, rs.AD_Site_Name0, rs.User_Domain0, rs.Full_Domain_Name0, rs.Operating_System_Name_and0, eps.Active, eps.EpInstalled, eps.EpProtected, 
                         dbo.v_GS_AntimalwareHealthStatus.Enabled, dbo.v_GS_AntimalwareHealthStatus.Version, dbo.v_GS_AntimalwareHealthStatus.AntivirusEnabled, dbo.v_GS_AntimalwareHealthStatus.AntispywareEnabled, 
                         dbo.v_GS_AntimalwareHealthStatus.EngineVersion, eps.EpToBeInstalled,
                             (SELECT        rua.ProductName0
                               FROM            dbo.v_GS_CCM_RECENTLY_USED AS rua
                               WHERE        (rs.ressourceID = rua.ressourceID)) AS Kaspersky
FROM            dbo.v_R_System AS rs INNER JOIN
                         dbo.v_EndpointProtectionStatus AS eps ON rs.ResourceID = eps.ResourceID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.v_GS_AntimalwareHealthStatus ON rs.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_AntimalwareHealthStatus.ResourceID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.v_GS_CCM_RECENTLY_USED_APPS AS rua ON rs.ResourceID = rua.ResourceID
```

TO be quick, I am trying to select if endpoint is enabled on the machine and if Kaspersky is also present.
But I can't figured it out! I don't know how to manage it because this query:

```
(SELECT        rua.ProductName0
                               FROM            dbo.v_GS_CCM_RECENTLY_USED AS rua
                               WHERE        (rs.ressourceID = rua.ressourceID)) AS Kaspersky
```

It returns multiple row (as they are multiple version of kaspersky installed on the target collection of computers.
But all I need is if it returns something (as it means that Kaspersky is present on the machine), then return something like "True" or "It's installed".

It's been a while since I have done some SQL query, so thank you in advance if you can help me with it.

Comment: read the help for SQL EXISTS ... https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp

Comment: I read it but I need it to return true (for example) if kaspersky exist... I will try to use it, with a IF statement. Maybe I can figure it out that way. Thank  you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found an answer and it this following one:

```
SELECT      rs.Name0, 
            rs.User_Name0, 
            rs.AD_Site_Name0, 
            rs.User_Domain0, 
            rs.Full_Domain_Name0, 
            rs.Operating_System_Name_and0, 
            eps.Active, 
            eps.EpInstalled, 
            eps.EpProtected, 
            eps.EpToBeInstalled,

            Case WHEN EXISTS (SELECT rua.ProductName0 FROM v_GS_CCM_RECENTLY_USED_APPS AS rua WHERE rs.resourceID = rua.resourceID AND rua.ProductName0 LIKE '%Kaspersky%') 
            THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
            END AS "Is Kaspersky installed?"

FROM            v_R_System AS rs INNER JOIN
                v_EndpointProtectionStatus AS eps ON rs.ResourceID = eps.ResourceID
```